# Not able to scrape Google Adsense

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-ads-api

I am trying to scrape a website and want to get the url's and images from Google AdSense. But it seems I am not getting any details of Google Adsense.

**Here I want**
If we search "refrigerator" in google then we will get some ads there which I need to fetch. Or some blogs, website showing Google Ads like See image

[image]

[image]

But when I inspect I can find related divs and url but when I hit url then i am getting only static html data.

Here is code which I need to fetch

[image: Screenshot from google search]

Here is script which I have written in Selenium, Python.

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://www.compiletimeerror.com/"

# use firefox to get page with javascript generated content
with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.get(url) # load page
    delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='pla-unit'])[0]")))
    print "Page is ready!"
    Element=browser.find_element(By.ID,value="google_image_div")
    print Element
    print Element.text
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

But I'm still unable to get data. Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: I see an `iframe` in the HTML, but I do not see you switching to it in your code.

Comment: @Sandip Armal Patil are you still looking for an answer here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first select the frame which contains the elements you want to work with.

```
select_frame("id=google_ads_frame1");
```

NOTE: I am not sure about the python syntax. But it should be something similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

Use Selenium's `switch_to.frame` method to direct your `browser` to the `iframe` in your html, before selecting your `element` variable (untested):

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://www.compiletimeerror.com/"

# use firefox to get page with javascript generated content
with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.get(url) # load page
    delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='pla-unit'])[0]")))
    print "Page is ready!"
    browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('google_ads_frame1'))
    element=browser.find_element(By.ID,value="google_image_div")
    print element
    print element.text
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/3-work-with-frames

A note on Python [style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Naming) best practices: use lowercase when declaring local variables (element vs. Element).